# Change height of StackView element afterwards

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uistackview

I have a `StackView` inside a `ScrollView` and inside that I have several `TextFields`. I would like to change one of the `textField.height` when that specific textfield begins to edit.

I tried it inside `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` but XCode breaks the `height.constraint`.

```
//delegate Methode für Password Textfield
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    switch textField {
    case passwordTextField:
        eyeButtonOne.isHidden = false
        passwordTextField.addSubview(checkLetterLabel)
        checkLetterLabel.addSubview(checkLetterImage)

        passwordTextField.addSubview(checkNumberLabel)
        checkNumberLabel.addSubview(checkNumberImage)

        passwordTextField.addSubview(checkLengthLabel)
        checkLengthLabel.addSubview(checkLengthImage)

        checkLetterLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        checkLetterLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkLetterImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 13).isActive = true

        checkLetterImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        checkLetterImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkLetterLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        checkLetterImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        checkLetterImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true

        checkNumberLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkLetterLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
        checkNumberLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkNumberImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 13).isActive = true

        checkNumberImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        checkNumberImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkNumberLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        checkNumberImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        checkNumberImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true

        checkLengthLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkNumberLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
        checkLengthLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkLengthImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 13).isActive = true

        checkLengthImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        checkLengthImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkLengthLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        checkLengthImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        checkLengthImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true

        passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        theStackView.layoutIfNeeded()


        break
    case passwordWiederholenTextField:
        eyeButtonTwo.isHidden = false
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    return true
}
```

Right now all the items are being displayed when `passwordTextField` `beginsEditing` but the height is not changing ... 
As you can see I am also calling `layoutIfNeeded()` but that doesn't do anything... I would also like to have some sort of Animation, nothing special it just should look smooth in the end.

Does anyone know how to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the height to break this means there is another 1 height constraint as this line

```
 passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
```

created another 1 , you need to add a variable

```
var heCon:NSLayoutConstraint!


heCon = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140)
heCon.isActive = true
```

then play with it's constant

```
heCon.constant = 100
theStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: I can not call `heCon.passwordTextField...`

Comment: 'Value of type 'NSLayoutConstraint' has no member 'passwordTextField'